# Python - Filter DataFrame via column-comparison with another df/list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dictionary of DataFrames which I've split up at the moment into single DataFrames because I don't know how to work on it directly in the dictionary. They are results of test specimen which look like this for example

```
T01
mm    N    Cycle
a     1      1
b     2      1
c     3      2
d     4      2
e     5      3
...   ...    ...
```

Now I have made another DataFrame (tried it with a list aswell) looking like this:

```
Cycles
1
3
5
...
```

My goal is to filter out every row where

```
Cycle != Cycles
```

So I get a list that looks like this:

```
mm    N    Cycle
a     1      1
b     2      1
e     5      3
f     6      3
...   ...    ...
```

I've created the DataFrames by this code:

```
for k,v in data_dict.items():    
    globals()[k] = (v[['mm','N', 'Unnamed: 3']])
    globals()[k].columns = ['mm', 'N', 'Cycles']
```

Now I have 7 different DataFrames with different sizes ranging from (2570, 3) to (12402, 3).

I've been looking around all the time but I can't seem to find a way that's working out. Maybe I shouldn't have used the globals()[k] call? I'm fairly new to python so I lack a lot of knowledge. Thank you in advance

Edit: I've been trying it with bool operations like

```
 globals()[k].query("Cycle" != Cycles['Cycles'])
```

or

```
 globals()[k][globals()[k].Cycle != Cycles['Cycles']]
```

But that's not doing anything for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have a list of cycles you want to filter for:

```
cycle_list = [1, 2, 3]
```

Now given a dictionary of dataframes `data_dict`, you can use a dictionary comprehension with Boolean masks to filter for rows satisfying your condition:

```
res = {k: v[v['Cycles'].isin(cycle_list)] for k, v in data_dict.items()}
```

This assumes each of your dataframes has a `Cycles` series. `pd.Series.isin` returns a series of Boolean values which are used to index your dataframe.

In addition, note that reasons for use of `globals()` are very rare; you should avoid calls to `globals` where possible.

Comment: So if I understand it right we create a new dictionary called "res" by iterating over the old dictionary. `for k, v in data_dict.items()` means `for every key: value pair in data_dict.items()` you look if `key: value[value of 'Cycles'] is in (cycle_list)`? Also why should I avoid calling globals and what should I use instead?

Comment: @Lumin, Yes, that's exactly the case. You may think it's inefficient to create a new dictionary. But it's not, it's O(n) complexity, which is the minimum possible given your data.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a dict of DataFrames let's call it `data_dict` and a list of Cycle `Cycles`.
You say you don't know how to handle a dictionnary of dataframes but that is actually the easy part once you know how to handle one dataframe since you just have to loop over it.
To solve your problem just use the `isin` method :

```
res = {}
for id, df in data_dict.items():
    #loop over the dataframes in the dict
    res[id] = df[df.Cycle.isin(Cycles)]
    #this is a new dataframe where you have only the cycles in Cycles
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

Say, your dataframes are defined as:

test = pd.DataFrame({'mm':['1','b','c','d','e'],'N':[1,2,3,4,5],'Cycle':[1,1,2,2,3]})

test2 = pd.DataFrame({'Cycles':[1,3,5]})

To filter out columns:

test3 = test[test.Cycle.isin(test2.Cycles)]

Out[19]: 
   Cycle  N mm
0      1  1  1
1      1  2  b
4      3  5  e